# UICollectionView selected cell become white in color?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The programming logic are as follow.
load the medias in album in background thread,
and every time, when the medias count % 30 == 0, it will reload the collectionView in main thread.

here is my code

the backgroundThread function

```
func backgroundThread(delay: Double = 0.0, background: (() -> Void)? = nil, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
            if(background != nil){ background!(); }

            let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if(completion != nil){ completion!(); }
            }
        }
    }
```

the loadMedia functions

```
func loadMedias() {
        Log.shareInstance.p("PTVideo - loadMedias begin", caller: self)
        assetLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos, usingBlock: { (grp: ALAssetsGroup!, groupBool: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
            // do something here
            if ALAssetsFilter.allVideos() != nil && grp != nil {
                if grp != nil {
                    grp.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock({ (asset, index, assetBool) -> Void in

                        if asset != nil  {
                                self.medias.append(asset!)
                            if(count(self.medias) % 30 == 0){
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                                    self.mediaCollection.reloadData()
                                })
                            }

                        }

                    })
                }
            }
            }) { (error) -> Void in
                // Handle error
                println("error in fetching assets")
        }

    }
```

and calling them in the viewDidLoad function in this way

```
self.backgroundThread(delay: 0, background: { () -> Void in
            self.loadMedias()
        }, completion: nil)
```

everything looks perfect, but when I click on the cell of collectionView, the cell become white as follow...
[image: white cell...]

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: ya, it is because the uicollectionview somehow selected the cell for many times, so the white square is actually, many white borders accumulate the make this, it turns out that I some how programmatically call didSelectCell for a cell for many times. Hope this can help you.